How to understand uniform central limit theorem
In a paper from Nickl I found a theorem 4 with a form of central limit theorem
$$\sqrt{n}(P_n-P)\rightarrow G$$
in $l^\infty(F)$ where $P$ is a law on $\mathbb{R}$, $F$ is a class of function and G a gaussian process index by $f\in F$. But the central limit theorem which I'm familiar with is like
$$f_n-f\rightarrow G$$
where G in index by $x\in\mathbb{R}$.
So how to understand the first version and can one transform it to the second version? Is it correct to demand $f\in F$ in the second version? Thanks a lot for any hint!

I found a little more details on this paper first page, but can't find any more fundamental explanation.
